# E: Unable to locate package python-pip

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python

I'm running ubuntu 20.04 (a clean install) I ran the command to install the universe repository which it said was already installed but for whatever reason it still says it can't find python-pip. I am able to install pip3 for python3 (but different projects use different versions of python so I'm trying to get this one to work) I'm wondering if python3 is the only supported apt package at this time or if I'm missing something?

This is the command I'm running: `sudo apt-get install python-pip`

And this is the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

Comment: Python2 is now EOL (https://pythonclock.org/) so it should be avoided. Any python2 scripts should have been converted to python3 last year (before the EOL of python2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package python-pip was removed in the upgrade to 20.04. This is because Ubuntu no longer supports Python 2.x.

If you are going to program in Python you will need to use Python 3 or higher.
To install pip3 (pip but for Python 3) type in `sudo apt install python3-pip`
Then `pip3 install MODULE`.